# How can I disable ssh logins for accounts?

Tags: ssh

I want to disable ssh logins for system accounts such as www-data, minidlna because I have a NTFS drive whose permissions are 7-7-7(rwxrwxrwx) and this causes everyone who logged in to the server to read my files. Therefore, I want to disable all logins and allow only a user to access via ssh.

I can disable root login changing PermitRootLogin value in sshd_config. However, there is no such option to disable all accounts another than the one I want.

I want to do that because I'm afraid that a program having a user on my system may have a default password entry that can be found on the Internet and someone can use my Linux remotely.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to change /etc/passwd and set the shell of that user to `/bin/false`.

Please see also:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22729/where-do-i-change-my-shell
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/whats-the-difference-between-sbin-nologin-and-bin-false